# 2002 Pontiac Grand Am will not start

Tags: starting, pontiac, grand-am

Had to tow the car from work, turn the key all lights as normal, but wont engage the starter. Jumped the starter, starter turns over the engine but motor will not start. replaced the entire ignition switch assembly, and let it relearn, still no start. Jumped the starter relay, starter cranks. Can hear fuel pump, and there is fuel pressure in the rails. Any other ideas why the key wont turn over the motor????

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Borrow or buy an OBD reader to see what trouble codes are stored.